# Linked List - Moving to the next node

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

So I'm having some trouble with a programming assignment about players sitting around a table. The program should be able to add players after the player who just took a turn. The assignment is supposed to show us how to add data into a linked list anywhere. So my problem occurs when I use a PLAY command. This should allow a single player to take a turn.

For example, if there are players A, B, and C, and the PLAY command is executed it will display to the console "Player A Takes a turn". If PLAY is executed again, it will display "Player B takes a turn."

My code allows the first player in the list to play, but does not move to the next node/player.

```
void CircleList::play()
{
    LinkedListOfPlayersNode *p=(*pFront).pNext;
    if (p->pData!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->pData->getName()+" takes a turn\n";
        p-> pNext; //My attempt to move to the next node.
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"There are no players. Please ADD a player.\n";
    }
}
```

So this obviously does not work. Can someone explain to me how I would move to the next player?

PS - code is in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a member in your class that retains the last player that took a turn.

```
class CircleList
{
   //...
   PlayerNode* pLastPlayer;
};
```

initially, this is set to `pFront` and you move it to the next player every time `play` is called.

```
void CircleList::play()
{
   //logic with pLastPlayer here

   //at the end move it
   pLastPlayer = pLastPlayer->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
p-> pNext; //My attempt to move to the next node.
```

doesn't move anything to the next node. 
You should probably store/assign `p->pNext`  to something.